# Rails on Subdomain and Custom Port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain, authlogic

I have to run rails on a shared host for a client via cPanel.

The application is running on a subdomain and non standard port.

I am using Authlogic, so on the first visit it detects I am not logged in and I get a page with:

`You are being redirected.`

Clicking on that I get the login form, which then takes me to the target page, with the same redirect message. So the model detects the login, but no cookie or session is ever created.

I have tried the following with no success:

`config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.bbbb.com'}`

I've also tried using an active record session with same result.

Please help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using, or have you looked at SubDomainFu?

http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu

Comment: I have used it before, not sure how it relates to my question at all?

Comment: fair enough, guess i don't understand the question, are you not able to set the session? Are you setting it and it is setting to the wrong value?

Comment: It appears the session is just never persisted. And redirects show that page saying "You will be redirected" rather than just redirecting